# Max and Min values according to the same job name and hour across different dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, worksheet-function, vba

I have the following table as an example of a huge three months of data:

```
JOB     LPAR  Hour  Date GCP_Sec    MIPS
XPTRE2@ DSYS    5   8/4  141.97      7.10
XPTRE2@ DSYS    1   8/4   57.57      2.88
XPTRE2@ DSYS    2   8/4   37.55      1.88
XPTRE2@ DSYS    5   8/5   61.19      3.06
XPTAB6# DSYS    4   8/6   76.58      3.83
XPTRE2@ DSYS    5   8/6  113.83      5.69
XPTAB6# DSYS    5   8/7   70.72      3.54
XPTRE2@ DSYS    7   8/7  226.98     11.35
XPTRE2@ DSYS    5   8/8  411.47     20.57
XPTRE2@ DSYS    9   8/9  476.63     23.83
XPTCEF$ DSYS    10  8/9  312.13     15.61
XPTRE2@ DSYS    5   8/10 237.59     11.88
```

I want to get, for example, the Max/Min/Avg MIPS for JOB name `XPTRE2@` on Hour `5` across all dates (8/4...8/9). I was thinking of an IF function then get the Max/Min/Avg but I don't know how to deal with the array.

What formula can be used or any way to get the Max/Min/Avg MIPS value according to the same `JOB` name and the `Hour` across all `Date`?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

[image: SO33085761 first example]

but with normal default settings that and much more is easier:

[image: SO33085761 second example]

The PT has `JOB` and below that `Hour` for ROWS and MIPS in the VALUES field three times, once each for Max, Min and Average.